# Using jQuery to make div's equal height

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make multiple div's on a page all the same height- the height of the tallest div. For instance, if there are 3 boxes on the page containing text, I want all of the boxes to be the height of the tallest box. This should be done automatically to all div's with the class `equalheight`. Here's what I have:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function equalHeight(group) {
        group.css('height','auto'); 
        var tallest = 0;
        group.each(function() {
           var thisHeight = $(this).height();
           if(thisHeight > tallest) {
              tallest = thisHeight;
           }
        });
        group.height(tallest);
    }
    equalHeight($(".equalheight"))

});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     equalHeight($(".equalheight"));

});
```

I could have sworn this used to work, but it isn't now. Perhaps some code got jumbled up somewhere and I haven't spotted it. Suggestions?

Comment: You can safely pull the `equalHeight` function out of the `DOM` ready handler and call the function only once.

Comment: And the rest of css for divs? After some testing, i get different results, based on, e.g. display property....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Sushanth said...

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    function equalHeight(group) {
        //group.css('height','auto'); 
        var tallest = 0;
        group.each(function() {
           var thisHeight = $(this).height();
           if(thisHeight > tallest) {
              tallest = thisHeight;
           }
        });
        group.height(tallest);
    }
    equalHeight($(".equalheight"))

});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     equalHeight($(".equalheight"));

});
```

```css
.red{
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="equalheight red" style="height:300px">
</div>
<div class="equalheight red">
</div>
<div class="equalheight red">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `group.css('height','auto');`